# regex negative float using kohana route

Tags: regex, kohana, routes

I would like to know why this regex is not working on kohana to retrieve a float negative number.

Regex :

```
^(-|)\d+((.|,)\d+|)$
```

Kohana route :

```
Route::set('route','data/<data>',array("data"=>"^(-|)\d+((.|,)\d+|)$"));
```

I tried this regex on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rH3xJ1) and it works, any idea why it doesn't on kohana route ?

thanks

Comment: `,` might be urlencoded and doesn't `.` need to be escaped? Also `?` is more readable than `(..|)` imo

Comment: You forgot a closing `'` after `data/<data>`. Also, you may want to remove the leading `^` and trailing `$`; I have no experience with Kohana, but I did not see these anchors being used in any of the examples in the [user guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing).

Comment: i've added the apostrophe thanks .. i think that kohana doesn't like "|"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is needlessly complex and has an error. The `.` in `(.|,)` doesn't match a period, but any character (the meaning of dot in regex, outside of character classes). We either need to escape the dot, as in `\.`, or to include it in a character class, as in `[.,]`

Try this compact regex instead:

`^-\d+[.,]\d+$` or `^-\d+([.,]\d+)?$` if you want to make the decimal part optional.

Your original regex suggested that you wanted to allow commas. If not, use this:

`^-\d+\.\d+$` or `^-\d+(\.\d+)?$` if you want to make the decimal part optional.

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
-                        # '-'
\d+                      # digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
[.,]                     # any character of: '.', ','
\d+                      # digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```

Comment: thank you for all these details its very useful, i'll mark your question as the good one =)

Comment: @zeomega Thanks, see you next time. :)